# Moment.js - Get difference in two birthdays in years, months and days

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm looking for a way to use momentjs to parse two dates, to show the difference.

I want to have it on the format: "X years, Y months, Z days".

For the years and months the moment library and modulo operator works nice. But for the days it's another tale as I don't want to handle leap years and all that by myself. So far the logic I have in my head is this:

```
var a = moment([2015, 11, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 06, 27]);

var years = a.diff(b, 'years');
var months = a.diff(b, 'months') % 12;
var days = a.diff(b, 'days');
// Abit stuck here as leap years, and difference in number of days in months. 
// And a.diff(b, 'days') returns total number of days.
return years + '' + months + '' + days;
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You could get the difference in years and add that to the initial date; then get the difference in months and add that to the initial date again.

In doing so, you can now easily get the difference in days and avoid using the modulo operator as well.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sd0qfqyy/)

```
var a = moment([2015, 11, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 06, 27]);

var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
b.add(years, 'years');

var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
b.add(months, 'months');

var days = a.diff(b, 'days');

console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
// 8 years 5 months 2 days
```

I'm not aware of a better, built-in way to achieve this, but this method seems to work well.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Should adding one year to 29 February return 28 February or 1 March? Should 31 May plus one month be 30 June or 1 July?

Comment: This answer gives correct years, months, days
when `b = moment([2007, 11, 29])`.  (8 years 0 months 0 days)

While @Kunal answer gave (8 years 0 months 1 days)

Comment: This is not return correct answers for who needs calendar months. var a = moment([2020, 03, 01]);
var b = moment([2020, 01, 31]); returns "0 years 0 months 30 days" But actually it should be 1 month & 2 days

Answer (score 41):

Moment.js also has [`duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) object. A moment is defined as single point in time, whereas duration is defined as a length of time which is basically what you want.

```
var a = moment([2015, 11, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 06, 27]);

var diffDuration = moment.duration(a.diff(b));

console.log(diffDuration.years()); // 8 years
console.log(diffDuration.months()); // 5 months
console.log(diffDuration.days()); // 2 days
```

What @Josh suggest may work, but is definitely not the right way of calculating difference in 2 moments.

Comment: Wrong answer for difference between `01/01/2013` and `01/01/2016`. It gives `2y 11m 29d` while Josh's answer gives `3y`.

Answer (score 3):

I just converted [@Josh Crozier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988284/6696353) into a function and added **hours**, **minutes** and **seconds** too.

```
 function diffYMDHMS(date1, date2) {

    let years = date1.diff(date2, 'year');
    date2.add(years, 'years');

    let months = date1.diff(date2, 'months');
    date2.add(months, 'months');

    let days = date1.diff(date2, 'days');
    date2.add(days, 'days');

    let hours = date1.diff(date2, 'hours');
    date2.add(hours, 'hours');

    let minutes = date1.diff(date2, 'minutes');
    date2.add(minutes, 'minutes');

    let seconds = date1.diff(date2, 'seconds');

    console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days ' + hours + ' 
    hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds'); 

    return { years, months, days, hours, minutes, seconds};
}
```

Comment: To make it a function, I suggest `clone()`ing arguments before calling `add()` because `date2` is mutated. Otherwise, there will be some unwanted cases with the passed moment instances in the client code (e.g. calling the function twice with same moment instances gives different results).

Answer (score 2):

Above solution is not working with momentjs 2.19.1

Then with reference of [Date of Joining calculation not working with moment 2.19.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727920/date-of-joining-calculation-not-working-with-moment-2-19-1) I have implemented new solution with **latest solution for momentjs 2.19.1**.

**Required npm packages**:

"[moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)": "^2.19.4",

"[moment-duration-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-duration-format)": "^1.3.0",

"[react-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment)": "^0.6.8",

**import following in reactjs**:

```
 import moment from "moment";
 import Moment from "react-moment";
 import momentDurationFormatSetup from "moment-duration-format";
```

---

```
var DOJ = moment([work_data.joining_date]).format("YYYY,MM,DD");      
var today = moment().format("YYYY,MM,DD");      
var totalMonths =  parseInt(moment(today).diff(moment(DOJ), 'months'));      
var totalDuration = moment.duration(totalMonths, "months").format();      
if(totalDuration.search('1y') > -1) {
   totalDuration = totalDuration.replace("1y", "1 Year,");
} else {
   totalDuration = totalDuration.replace("y", " Years,");
}

if(totalDuration.search('1m') > -1){
  totalDuration = totalDuration.replace("1m", "1 Month");
} else {
  totalDuration = totalDuration.replace("m", " Months");
}

console.log(totalDuration);
```

Answer (score 1):

All the solutions presented here are failing for some of the test cases. So I made some changes to the accepted answer.

```
function getYMD(date1, date2) {
    const a = moment(date1);
    const b = moment(date2);
    var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
    b.add(years, 'years');

    const noOfDaysInb = b.daysInMonth();
    const noOfDaysIna = a.daysInMonth();
    let months = 0;
    if (noOfDaysInb > noOfDaysIna) {
        months = b.diff(a, "months");
        a.add(months, "months");
    } else {
        months = a.diff(b, 'months');
        b.add(months, 'months');
    }
    var days = a.diff(b, 'days');
    return {
        years: Math.abs(years),
        months: Math.abs(months),
        days: Math.abs(days),
    }
}
```

This is the best answer I can come up with.

Answer (score -1):

This is another answer. Verified with Age Calculator

```
function calculateAge(){
    ageText = jQuery("#dob").closest(".form-group").find(".age-text");
    ageText.text("");
    level2.dob = jQuery("#dob").val();
    if(!level2.dob) return;
    level2.mdob= moment(level2.dob, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    if(!level2.mdob.isValid()){
        alert("Invalid date format");
        return;
    }
    level2.targetDate = moment();//TODO: Fill in the target date
    level2.months = level2.targetDate.diff(level2.mdob, 'months'); // Calculate the months
    let years = parseInt(level2.months/12); // A year has 12 months irrespective or leap year or not
    let balanceMonths = level2.months%12; // The balance gives the number of months 
    let days;
    if(!balanceMonths){ // If no balance months, then the date selected lies in the same month
        months = 0; // so months = 0
        days = level2.targetDate.diff(level2.mdob, 'days'); // only the days difference
    }else{
    months = balanceMonths;
    dob_date = level2.mdob.date();
    target_month = level2.targetDate.month();
    construct_date = moment().month(target_month).date(dob_date);
    days = level2.targetDate.diff(construct_date, 'days')+1; // There might be one day missed out. Not sure on UTC
}

ageText = years +" years " + months+ " months " + days +" days";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
  var totalDays = endDate.diff(startDate, "days");
```

Comment: This only gives the entire amount of days.