# Date of Joining calculation not working with moment 2.19.1

Tags: momentjs

Below code not working with "moment": "^2.19.1",

```
var a = moment([2017, 12, 09]);
var b = moment([2011, 02, 17]);

var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
b.add(years, 'years');

var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
b.add(months, 'months');

var days = a.diff(b, 'days');
console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment duration format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format).

Include moment duration format plugin, and then..

```
var duration = moment.duration(a.diff(b));
console.log(duration.format('y [years] m [months] d [days]'));
```