# Flutter - How to find difference between two dates in years, months and days?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, date-difference

I'm looking for a way to use `DateTime` to parse two dates, to show the difference.
I want to have it on the format: "X years, Y months, Z days".

For JS, we have `momentjs` library and [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33988284)::

```
var a = moment([2015, 11, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 06, 27]);

var years = a.diff(b, 'year');
b.add(years, 'years');

var months = a.diff(b, 'months');
b.add(months, 'months');

var days = a.diff(b, 'days');

console.log(years + ' years ' + months + ' months ' + days + ' days');
// 8 years 5 months 2 days
```

Is there similar library available for **dart** that can help achieve this usecase?

Answer (score 10):

I think it is not possible to do exactly what you want easily with DateTime. Therefore you can use https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine package that is quite powerful with date time handling:

```dart
import 'package:time_machine/time_machine.dart';

void main() {
  LocalDate a = LocalDate.today();
  LocalDate b = LocalDate.dateTime(DateTime(2022, 1, 2));
  Period diff = b.periodSince(a);
  print("years: ${diff.years}; months: ${diff.months}; days: ${diff.days}");
}
```

for hours/minutes/seconds precision:

```dart
import 'package:time_machine/time_machine.dart';

void main() {
  LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.now();
  LocalDateTime b = LocalDateTime.dateTime(DateTime(2022, 1, 2, 10, 15, 47));
  Period diff = b.periodSince(a);
  print("years: ${diff.years}; months: ${diff.months}; days: ${diff.days}; hours: ${diff.hours}; minutes: ${diff.minutes}; seconds: ${diff.seconds}");
}
```

Comment: How would you extend this to get hours minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is the Dart [DateTime class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)
You can get close to what you want in moment.js with

```
main() {
  var a = DateTime.utc(2015, 11, 29);
  var b = DateTime.utc(2007, 06, 27);

  var years = a.difference(b);
  print(years.inDays ~/365);

}
```

There is no inYears or inMonths option for DateTime though that's why the year is divided in the print.
the difference function returns the difference in seconds so you have to process it yourself to days.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks

Comment: This one is actually the best answer

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate from the total number of days:

```
void main() {
  DateTime a = DateTime(2015, 11, 29);
  DateTime b = DateTime(2007, 06, 27);
  int totalDays = a.difference(b).inDays;
  int years = totalDays ~/ 365;
  int months = (totalDays-years*365) ~/ 30;
  int days = totalDays-years*365-months*30;
  print("$years $months $days $totalDays");
}
```

Result is: 8 5 7 3077

Comment: Required difference in year, month and days. read question carefully

Comment: @AbdulQadir from number of days you can easily calculate the other numbers; I added some code to show.

Comment: `months` calculation is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Jiffy Package](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy) for this like this

```
var jiffy1 = Jiffy("2008-10", "yyyy-MM");
var jiffy2 = Jiffy("2007-1", "yyyy-MM");

jiff1.diff(jiffy2, Units.YEAR); // 1
jiff1.diff(jiffy2, Units.YEAR, true);
```

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer...

Answer (score 2):

You could write an extension on duration class to format it:

```
extension DurationExtensions on Duration {
  String toYearsMonthsDaysString() {
    final years = this.inDays ~/ 365
    // You will need a custom logic for the months part, since not every month has 30 days
    final months = (this.inDays ~% 365) ~/ 30
    final days = (this.inDays ~% 365) ~% 30

    return "$years years $months months $days days";
  }
}
```

The usage will be:

```
final date1 = DateTime()
final date2 = DateTime()
date1.difference(date2).toYearsMonthsDaysString()
```

Answer (score 2):

I created my own class for Gregorian Dates, and I created a method which handle this issue, it calculates "logically" the difference between two dates in years, months, and days...
i actually created the class from scratch without using any other packages (including DateTime package) but here I used DateTime package to illustrate how this method works.. until now it works fine for me...

method to determine if it's a leap year or no:

```
    static bool leapYear(DateTime date) {
    if(date.year%4 == 0) {
      if(date.year%100 == 0){
        return date.year%400 == 0;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

this is the method which calculates the difference between two dates in years, months, and days. it puts the result in a list of integers:

```
     static List<int> differenceInYearsMonthsDays(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) {
    List<int> simpleYear = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
    if(dt1.isAfter(dt2)) {
      DateTime temp = dt1;
      dt1 = dt2;
      dt2 = temp;
    }
    int totalMonthsDifference = ((dt2.year*12) + (dt2.month - 1)) - ((dt1.year*12) + (dt1.month - 1));
    int years = (totalMonthsDifference/12).floor();
    int months = totalMonthsDifference%12;
    late int days;
    if(dt2.day >= dt1.day) {days = dt2.day - dt1.day;}
    else {
      int monthDays = dt2.month == 3
          ? (leapYear(dt2)? 29: 28)
          : (dt2.month - 2 == -1? simpleYear[11]: simpleYear[dt2.month - 2]);
      int day = dt1.day;
      if(day > monthDays) day = monthDays;
      days = monthDays - (day - dt2.day);
      months--;
    }
    if(months < 0) {
      months = 11;
      years--;
    }
    return [years, months, days];
  }
```

the method which calculates the difference between two dates in months, and days:

```
static List<int> differenceInMonths(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2){
    List<int> inYears = differenceInYearsMonthsDays(dt1, dt2);
    int difMonths = (inYears[0]*12) + inYears[1];
    return [difMonths, inYears[2]];
  }
```

the method which calculates the difference between two dates in days:

```
static int differenceInDays(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) {
    if(dt1.isAfter(dt2)) {
      DateTime temp = dt1;
      dt1 = dt2;
      dt2 = temp;
    }
    return dt2.difference(dt1).inDays;
  }
```

usage example:

```
void main() {
  DateTime date1 = DateTime(2005, 10, 3);
  DateTime date2 = DateTime(2022, 1, 12);
  List<int> diffYMD = GregorianDate.differenceInYearsMonthsDays(date1, date2);
  List<int> diffMD = GregorianDate.differenceInMonths(date1, date2);
  int diffD = GregorianDate.differenceInDays(date1, date2);

  print("The difference in years, months and days: ${diffYMD[0]} years, ${diffYMD[1]} months, and ${diffYMD[2]} days.");
  print("The difference in months and days: ${diffMD[0]} months, and ${diffMD[1]} days.");
  print("The difference in days: $diffD days.");
}
```

output:

```
The difference in years, months and days: 16 years, 3 months, and 9 days.
The difference in months and days: 195 months, and 9 days.
The difference in days: 5945 days.
```

Answer (score 2):

try intl package with the following code:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

String startDate = '01/01/2021';
String endDate = '01/01/2022';

final start = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(startDate);
final end = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(endDate);
```

Then, you can calculate the duration between the two dates with the following code:

```
final duration = end.difference(start);
```

To obtain the number of years, months and days, you can do the following:

```
final years = duration.inDays / 365;
final months = duration.inDays % 365 / 30;
final days = duration.inDays % 365 % 30;
```

Finally, you can use these variables to display the result in the desired format:

```
    final result = '${years.toInt()} years ${months.toInt()} months y ${days.toInt()} days';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

the answer is yes, you can easilly achieve it with DateTime class in Dart. See: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/DateTime-class.html

Example

```
void main() {
  var moonLanding = DateTime(1969,07,20)
  var marsLanding = DateTime(2024,06,10);
  var diff = moonLanding.difference(marsLanding);

  print(diff.inDays.abs());
  print(diff.inMinutes.abs());
  print(diff.inHours.abs());
}
```

outputs:
20049
28870560
481176

Comment: indays() will give the total duration in days, so is inhours() and in mitutes(). in order to get te result you need, you need to divide the inDays() with 365 (for years). like wise apply logic for months and days,

Comment: yeah, agree here, it requires some additional computation to get years and months. Can be Alex answer using time_machine lib below is more suitable to get exact numbers. But for approximate data +- 1 day I would say multiplying days by 30 and years by 365 days could also serve, depending on the use case.

Comment: Dividing by 365 will not be leap-year compliant!  You'll be off by approx. 10 days every 40 years if my experimentation is anything to go by.

Answer (score 1):

```
final firstDate = DateTime.now();
final secondDate = DateTime(firstDate.year, firstDate.month - 20);

final yearsDifference = firstDate.year - secondDate.year;
final monthsDifference = (firstDate.year - secondDate.year) * 12 +
    firstDate.month - secondDate.month;
final totalDays = firstDate.difference(secondDate).inDays;
```

Simple approach, no packages needed.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime difference in years is a specific function, like this:

```
  static int getDateDiffInYear(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo) {
    int sign = 1;
    if (dateFrom.isAfter(dateTo)) {
      DateTime temp = dateFrom;
      dateFrom = dateTo;
      dateTo = temp;
      sign = -1;
    }
    int years = dateTo.year - dateFrom.year;
    int months = dateTo.month - dateFrom.month;
    if (months < 0) {
      years--;
    } else {
      int days = dateTo.day - dateFrom.day;
      if (days < 0) {
        years--;
      }
    }
    return years * sign;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer might be a little long but will give you what you need.

This will give you the values as a String in the format "Year : year, Months: month, Days: days". You can change it according to your need.

You need to call differenceInYearsMonthsAndDays() and pass the startDate and endDate.

An Extension to calculate the differents in Months discarding the excess days.

```
extension DateTimeUtils on DateTime {
  int differenceInMonths(DateTime other) {
    if (isAfter(other)) {
      if (year > other.year) {
        if (day >= other.day) {
          return (12 + month) - other.month;
        } else {
          return (12 + month - 1) - other.month;
        }
      } else {
        if (day >= other.day) {
          return month - other.month;
        } else {
          return month - 1 - other.month;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

A Method to generate the Year, Month and Day Format

```
String differenceInYearsMonthsAndDays(
  DateTime startDate,
  DateTime endDate,
) {
  int days;
  final newStartDate = startDate.add(const Duration(days: -1));
  int months = endDate.differenceInMonths(newStartDate);
  if(months >= 12) {
    final years = months ~/ 12;
    final differenceInMonthsAndDays = differenceInMonthsAndDays(
          startDate.add(const Duration(year: years), 
          endDate,
    );
    return "Years : years, $differenceInMonthsAndDays";
  } else {
    return differenceInMonthsAndDays(
          startDate, 
          endDate,
    );
  }

}
```

A Method to generate the Month and Day Format

```
String differenceInMonthsAndDays(
  DateTime startDate,
  DateTime endDate,
) {
  int days;
  final newStartDate = startDate.add(const Duration(days: -1));
  int months = endDate.differenceInMonths(newStartDate);


  if (months > 0) {
    final tempDate = DateTime(
      newStartDate.year,
      newStartDate.month + months,
      newStartDate.day,
    );
    days = endDate.difference(tempDate).inDays;
    return days > 0 
       ? "Months : $months, Days : $days" 
       : "Months : $months";
  } else {
    days = endDate.difference(newStartDate).inDays;
    return "Days : $days";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Years and months are somewhat of a special case. Most of the replies above do not account for leap years (not all years have 365 days so dividing by it might give you wrong results in some cases) and the fact that not all months are 30 days long..

The easiest way I found to **calculate number of years** that passed since a certain date is following:

```
int _getYearDifference(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    var diff = to.year - from.year;
    if (to.month < from.month || (to.month == from.month && to.day < from.day)) {
        diff--;
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Similarly for **months**:

```
int _getMonthDifference(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
  int yearDiff = to.year - from.year;
  int monthDiff = max(to.month - from.month, 0);

  int diff = yearDiff * 12 + monthDiff;

  if (monthDiff > 0 && to.day < from.day) {
    diff--;
  }

  return diff;
}
```

For **days and shorter intervals** you can use the standard `difference()` method:

```
var diff = to.difference(from);
print(diff.inDays.abs());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
final DateTime end = DateTime(2030);
int seconds = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int hours = 0;
int days = 0;
int months = 0;
int years = 0;

final Duration remainedDuration = end.difference(now);

void calculateDiff() {
      seconds = remainedDuration.inSeconds;
      minutes = seconds ~/ 60;
      seconds = seconds % 60;
      if (minutes < 60) return;
      hours = minutes ~/ 60;
      minutes = minutes % 60;
      if (hours < 24) return;
      days = hours ~/ 24;
      hours = hours % 60;
      if (days < 30) return;
      months = days ~/ 30;
      days = days % 30;
      if (months < 12) return;
      years = months ~/ 12;
      months = months % 12;
}

calculateDiff();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
difHour = someDateTime.difference(DateTime.now()).inHours;
    difMin = (someDateTime.difference(DateTime.now()).inMinutes)-(difHour*60);
```

and same for years and days