# Difference duration between two dates - Dart

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, momentjs

I'm trying to ind the duration difference between two dates for the respective units in Dart. I'm looking at [jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy/example) since it was inspired by moment.js and in moment.js that would be achieved by the following snippet:

```
const dateOne= moment('3/29/2020','M/D/YYYYY'); //29th March 2020
const currentDate = moment();
// get the difference between the moments
const diff = currentDate.diff(dateOne);
//express as a duration
const diffDuration = moment.duration(diff);

const diffDuration = {
  months: diffDuration.months(), //6 months
  days: diffDuration.days(), //14 days
  hours: diffDuration.hours(), //21 hours
  minutes: diffDuration.minutes(), //55 minutes
  seconds: diffDuration.seconds(), //44 seconds
}
```

But with Jiffy I can only find the difference, not the difference duration

```
var jiffy1 = Jiffy(); //get current time
var jiffy2 = Jiffy("2020-03-29", "yyyy-MM-dd");
var _months = jiffy1.diff(jiffy2, Units.MONTH); //6 
var _days = jiffy1.diff(jiffy2, Units.DAY); //197 days
var _hours = jiffy1.diff(jiffy2, Units.HOUR); //284,99 hours
var _seconds = jiffy1.diff(jiffy2, Units.SECOND );
var _minutes = jiffy1.diff(jiffy2, Units.MINUTE);
```

Is there any way to achieve that functionality in Dart (Flutter) it doesn't have to be with a package. I did consider the DateTime class but it seems to give the same output as well, just with less units avaliable

Comment: There are many answers to this, here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713115/flutter-finding-difference-between-two-dates Datetime class and Duration class are the way to go

Comment: @GrahamD that gives the difference sure but I'm looking for the difference duration? I'm not sure if I'm phrasing that properly. Let's say I had a start date of March 1st and and end date of April 1st. The difference between those two is 32 days. But I want the final output to be 1 month 1 day.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Maybe this https://pub.dev/packages/simple_moment and this https://pub.dev/packages/date_util could help?

Comment: @GrahamD thanks! I'll give them a go and update this question as I go along

Comment: @GrahamD got the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With much thanks to Alex on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170347/flutter-how-to-find-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-and-days/62170813?noredirect=1#comment113983943_62170813) I've resolved it using the [time_machine](https://pub.dev/packages/time_machine) package

```
import 'package:time_machine/time_machine.dart';
LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime b = LocalDateTime.dateTime(DateTime(2020, 3, 29, 0, 0, 0));
Period diff = a.periodSince(b);
var _months = diff.months;
var _days = diff.days;
var _hours = diff.hours;
var _seconds = diff.seconds;
var _minutes = diff.minutes;
print("years: ${diff.years}; months: ${diff.months}; days: ${diff.days}; hours: ${diff.hours}; minutes: ${diff.minutes}; seconds: ${diff.seconds}");
```

Don't forget to use `LocalDateTime` and not just `LocalDate` if you want the time difference as well