# Flutter: calculate months difference between 2 dates

Tags: flutter

I've got an app to manage rents. The lease periods are:

```
List<String> rentPeriods = [
    'daily',
    'weekly',
    'bimonthly',
    'monthly',
    '2_months',
    'quarterly',
    'biannual',
    'annual',
  ];
```

I need to display how many payments will the user have for that lease. For daily and weekly I do something like this:

```
final dailyPayments = to.difference(from).inDays;
final weeklyPayments = to.difference(from).inDays / 7;
```

But when I need to calculate months how could I do it? I can't just divide it by 30

Comment: This library considers months differences, maybe can fit you your need https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy

Comment: [This post has the answer to your question using timemachine package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170347/flutter-how-to-find-difference-between-two-dates-in-years-mo[nths-and-days])

Comment: I was already using that package but how can I convert the different into months?