# I want to get the difference between two dates in years, months and days

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to get the difference between two dates in Years, months, days. I've tried everything I know so far but so far I am not getting what I was tending to get.

This is my last try, the problem with it is that I am getting 5 years converted into months and days instead of getting the difference in years left, months left and days,

```
button.addEventListener('click',()=>{

 let m = moment(selectDate.value);
 let applyingDate = m.add(5,"years");
 let cur = moment();
 let diff = applyingDate - cur;
 let years = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60*24)/365);
 let months = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60*24)/365/12);
 let days = Math.floor(diff/(1000*60*60*24)/30);


console.log(years,months,days);
});
```

any help, please ? An explanation of the concept would be so much appreciated <3

Comment: is it possible for you to convert it to unix time and do the math instead? would you get too much of a performance hit if you convert back and forth?

Comment: I am so open to anything as far as it does the job

Comment: this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732897/difference-between-two-dates-in-years-months-days-in-javascript

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988129/moment-js-get-difference-in-two-birthdays-in-years-months-and-days#answer-34001163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are already using `moment.js`, I suggest you take a look at their [durat section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/diffing/) on the docs as it provides a very nice way to do what you need.

For your use case, I believe this solves your problem:

```js
let m = moment(selectDate.value);
let applyingDate = m.add(5,"years");
let cur = moment();

const diffDuration = moment.duration(applyingDate.diff(cur))

return [
  diffDuration.years(),
  diffDuration.months(),
  diffDuration.days()
]
```

It's very similar to [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk7crh5z/) I created

Comment: yes but what i want is something like (period left : 2 years, 5 months and 3 days ), this is the format I want, the code above return the period of 5 years  and convert it to months and days , and that is not what I am looking for 


thank you

Comment: @KhaledBerhane I edited the answer to match what I believe is your use case.
In case it's not, can you please provide the input and the expected output?